# how to fast set the bitset by using multiple position once

Tags: c++, simd, bitset, bitvector

how to fast set the bitset by using multiple position, eg: the position : 1,4,5,6,9,3. the bitset is 0101111001....,whether can use SIMD instruction?
I know the simple method, eg: assume the word_t is unsigned char:

```
void set_bit(word_t* bitset, int position) {
  int index= position / std::numeric_limits<word_t>::digits;
  int offset = position % std::numeric_limits<word_t>::digits;
  bitset[index] |= (1U << (std::numeric_limits<word_t>::digits -1 - offset));
}
```

Comment: You can sort all lowbit (with their mask/bitset) values and process them in sequence to have better cache-line usage.

Comment: Your code does not match your description.

Comment: In what form do you get multiple positions? How close are they in general? How big is your bit-set? How large is `word_t` or the biggest native integer on your target system? What SIMD instruction set do you have?

Comment: Can you assume a CPU with somewhat efficient unaligned loads?  You could `memcpy(&tmp, static_cast<char*>(bitset)[lowbit], sizeof(tmp))` to load, `tmp &= mask;` and another memcpy to do an unaligned store.  (It seems `lowbit` is a byte offset, not a bit-index, since you're not using CHAR_BIT or `std::numeric_limits<word_t>::digits`, so your mask is always byte-aligned.  Or is that just a bug, since you're bit-shifting `mask << offset` by a byte offset?)

Comment: @chtz the bitset size is 256 or 512 bit, so the positions's size is <= 256 or 512,  the word_t can be unsigned char *.....the SIMD instruction is not limited

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe I haven't made it clear yet, and I've revised my statement and code

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow sorry,Maybe I haven't made it clear yet, and I've revised my statement and code

Comment: Ok, yeah, your code is clearly broken.  `sizeof` returns the size in bytes (actually `char`), so `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 in the C++ standard.  So `offset = position % 1` is always `0`, and `1U << (1-1 - 0)` is a no-op, setting the low bit of `bitset[index]`. At least now we know what you wanted your code to do (basically emulate std::bitset or `vector<bool>`), but now we have much less information about how you could receive a set of multiple bits. Previously you had a mask, so you could have your caller already do the work of turning bit indices into bit-positions within an integer.

Comment: (To fix your example, like I said you want `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(word_t)`, or `std::numeric_limits<word_t>::digits`, for the number of bits in a `word_t`.)

Comment: Do you have to number bits backwards like this, where bit 0 is the most-significant in the low `word_t`?  Are you on PowerPC or something where that's the standard conventions?  Most people would just use `1U << offset` to match what 386 instructions like `bts` do, because most people number bits within a byte with 0 as the least-significant bit.  i.e. `3` has bits #0 and #1 set.  If you need to negate or NOT your shift counts after a modulo, that could take extra work (even on PowerPC, I think.)  Unless maybe you start with an `INT_MIN` constant and right-shift that?

Comment: Why not just use `std::bitset`?

Comment: Is converting a list of positions to a bitset really the bottleneck in your program? Do you want to write a `void set_positions(word_t* bitset, std::vector<int> positions)` that combines all the positions belonging to the same `word_t` into a single write to bitset? If `positions` is sorted this would be relatively easy to do using a temp variable and a loop. But the extra branches would probably make this slower than just setting the bits. And if `positions` is not sorted then sorting will add a lot of cost to it on top.

Comment: If there are a lot of positions per `word_t` to set then maybe change the code that generates that list of positions to generate a bitset directly. An `std::vector<int> positions` is only better if you have less than 1 in 32 bits set.

Comment: *the SIMD instruction is not limited* - So we can pick whichever of ARM64 SVE or ASIMD, RISC-V vector extensions, PowerPC Altivec, or x86 AVX-512 VBMI2 or AMD XOP has the most useful features?  Is this for portable code so you want versions for each ISA or extension-level?  Or a hypothetical exercise so we could even use future SIMD instructions that haven't been release yet, if any proved useful?

Comment: @PeterCordes oh, yeah, my code have some broken, i want to express the sizeof(unsigned char) is 8 bit, so the size we should use 8.  I wanted to speed up the process of this setup as much as possible, so I thought about whether it was possible to pass the simd instructions

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the positions is not sorted, yeah, my programing  has a lot of loop to set the bitset by multiple positions that stored in the array, so i think is the  bottleneck in my program.  so I thought about whether it was possible to pass the simd. the bitset is 256 bit

Comment: With AVX-512F `vpcompressd`, you could select out indices below 64, for example.  That could set up for doing a variable-shift for those (`vpsllvq`), and horizontally ORing together with some shuffling to make a single mask for the low 8 bytes.  Doing the same thing for indices from 64-127 would let you build an 8-byte mask for the 2nd 8-byte chunk.  That would mean looking at every bit-position 4 times (once per "bucket"), with subtract and compare-into-mask, left-packing into a bucket.  But in groups of 16 at once, and you can bail out early if there are no set bits in that range.

Comment: @why Why do you have positions stored in an array? If converting positions into bitset is such a bottleneck then optimize earlier where you create the array. That will gain you much more.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank, Your knowledge reserve is really rich, I would like to ask you to write a pseudocode, I still can't understand its specific implementation, thank you！